# Selenium C# Clicking the wrong tablerow

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to solve the question about clicking on a certain row wich is formulated on the following page: https://testwisely.com/demo/event-table. I came upon this question by reading the book Selenium WebDriver Recipes in C#.  I have a written a pageobject class ass follows:

```
    public void ClickTableLink(String issueNumber)
    {
        ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> tableRows =
            driver.FindElements(
                By.XPath(
                    ".//*[@id='complaintsTable']/tbody/tr[contains (@class, 'gridLayoutEvenRow' ) or contains(@class, 'gridLayoutOddRow')]"));
        foreach (IWebElement row in tableRows)
        {
            try
            {
                row.FindElement(By.XPath("td[contains(text(), '" + issueNumber + "')]"))
                    .FindElement(By.XPath("//td/a"))
                    .Click();
                break;
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Problem is that no matter with what issueNumber I call this method the click is always on the Link in the first row. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment about using a direct approach vs using a table you could also just do the below using string replacement.

```
        Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//td[contains(text(), '{0}')]//preceding-sibling::td/a", issueNumber))).Click();
```

Comment: I prefer this answer because it's compact and still works when an extra column is inserted in the table (as long as it's inserted to the left of the column with the issue number)

Answer (score 0):

You might try this. It will loop through and find the issue number. Then if you look at `tds[i - 3].Click();` it will look at 3 columns to the left of the issueNumber and click it. You can go to the right of issueNumber using + 3. Just change that value according to what column it is in in relation to issueNumber.

```
  public void ClickTableLink(String issueNumber)
   {
      var table =  driver.FindElement(By.Id("complaintsTable"));
    foreach (var tr in table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr")))
    {
       var tds = tr.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
        for (var i = 0; i < tds.Count; i++)
        {
            if (tds[i].Text.Trim().Contains(issueNumber))
            {
                tds[i - 3].Click();
               break;
            }

        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can basically do this with a one-liner using XPath. The XPath would look for a TD that contains the desired issue number, find the parent TR, and then find the child TD with the id="applicationDateId". I would wrap this in a function so that it's reusable.

```
static void ClickEvent(string issueNumber)
{
    Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[td[contains(., '" + issueNumber + "')]]/td/a")).Click();
}
```

You would call it like,

```
 ClickEvent("2898");
```

Comment: Although it looks like an elegant solution to me it's only working with the issue number of the first row. When passing the issue number of the second row to the method it's giving a NoSuchElementException. I'm busy to figure out how to modify the XPath expression to get it work for the second row too.

Comment: I fixed it. It turned out that that formatting wasn't consistent in each row. All I did was remove the reference to the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Because I like the elegance of the answer I tried to get the answer of @JeffC working but without success, probably because my knowledge of XPath expressions is not sufficient. After some changes I managed to get the answer of @Dazed working.

```
    public void ClickTableLink(String issueNumber)
    {
        var table = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
        foreach (var tr in table)
        {
            var tds = tr.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
            for (var i = 0; i < tds.Count; i++)
            {
                if (tds[i].Text.Trim().Contains(issueNumber))
                {
                    tds[i - 3].Click();
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: weird you had to change anything. I tested that code in my environment and it was working fine.  That first call just identified the table. The rest pull out tags accordingly. The beauty of this code is that you can write asserts and validate the data in each row. Please accept the answer to close this one out.

Comment: I had to change because the statement table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"))) is giving the error: ReadOnlyCollection <IWebElement> does not contain a defenition for FindElements and no extension method FindElements accepting a first argument of type ReadOnlyCollection <IWebElement> could be found.

Comment: Maybe you are missing some using statements? I posted another solution for you also using a direct approach. I thought you wanted to loop through the table based on your original post. When it comes to tables, I prefer to get all of the table elements because it is just easier to work with in the long run.

Comment: My IDE, VS2015 with Resharper installed, is not giving me any clue what Using to choose for making it possible to use FindElements on a collection of IWebElements, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I found it. My bad. This was using "FindElements" instead of "FindElement". All of my calls are methods so I have to change them a bit when posting back here.  var table =  driver.FindElement(By.Id("complaintsTable"));